# using the variable from the case clause in "where" statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

In my SQL query I have a CASE clause. How can I use the variable name from the CASE in where statment. This is my query

```
SElECT 
    a,
    b,

    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE AVG(CAST([y] as DECIMAL(9,2))) /  AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) 
    END AS z

FROM magic_table
WHERE  z > 0
GROUP BY a,b
```

here I can not grab the z in where clause. But How can I do it ? is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: `Z` is a column alias, not a variable. You can't use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause that created that column. You'd have to repeat the expression BUT you can't use an aggregate method in `WHERE`. You need to use `HAVING`.

Comment: Assuming `x` and `y` are numbers, the *actual* expression you need is `HAVING AVG(x)!=0 AND AVG(y)>0`.

Comment: How can I rewrite it in a complete statement ?

Comment: The docs for the [HAVING clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) have a lot of examples

Comment: I understood the idea behind it. But that does not help me to get through my goal. The case condition filters out the zero related problem, z gives me the output without any error. I need to take only those values ehich are bigger then 0 for z

Comment: I already posted this. `HAVING AVG(x)!=0 AND AVG(y)>0`. `z` can only be positive if that condition holds. You don't need the casts or the CASE.

Comment: A shorter version of that `CASE` would be `AVG(CAST(y as DECIMAL(9,2))) /  NULLIF(AVG(CAST(x as DECIMAL(9,2))), 0)` and you can use that in `HAVING` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Panagiotis Kanavos already commented you cant use column alias in where statement but you can put your whole case statement in HAVING clause like so:

```
SElECT 
    a,
    b,
    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE AVG(CAST([y] as DECIMAL(9,2))) /  AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) 
    END AS z

FROM magic_table
GROUP BY a,b
HAVING CASE 
        WHEN AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE AVG(CAST([y] as DECIMAL(9,2))) /  AVG(CAST([x] as DECIMAL(9,2))) 
    END > 0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for showing me the application in this context

Comment: This is wrong. There's no reason to repeat the entire expression.

Comment: Show us the right way please

Comment: @AnonymousScientificUser it's not perfect, it's wrong. I already posted the exact full expression you need. `z` can't be 0 unless `AVG(X)` is 0 or `AVG(Y)` is 0. The casts aren't needed

Comment: I think there is a small misunderstanding here. I do not need to varify the condition of not zeo here. I need to see if the divisio ( after the monitoring ) is bigger then 0

Comment: Yes, and the only way this can be true is for `AVG(X)` to be non-zero and `AVG(Y)` to be positive. `HAVING AVG(X)!=0 AND AVG(Y)>0`